# iPad Air 2 iOS9 app crash in many places

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, ios9

My app go normally on iOS 5 - 9, on every iPad models.
But on iPad Air 2 sometimes runs normally, sometimes crash in many miscellaneous places. I can't write code in this post, its very big and as I write it crash in many other places. Sometimes miscellaneous variables are nil, sometimes are ok.  Sometimes app crash, but variables are not nil and not zombie or garbage.

This are examples of the debugger **bt**:

Example #1:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2af45, 0x000000011130b817       libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2267f9c40)
frame #0: 0x000000011130b817 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23
frame #1: 0x000000010fa7308f UIKit`-[UIWindow _setAttachedToScene:] + 75
frame #2: 0x000000010fa764f3 UIKit`-[UIWindow _updateLayerOrderingAndSetLayerHidden:] + 93
frame #3: 0x000000010fa89034 UIKit`-[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 63
frame #4: 0x000000010fdad614 UIKit`-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2646
frame #5: 0x000000010fdaf53d UIKit`-[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 223
frame #6: 0x000000010fa0df5e UIKit`-[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 57
frame #7: 0x000000010fa0e33c UIKit`-[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260
frame #8: 0x000000010fa0cca1 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1383
frame #9: 0x000000010fa09ff0 UIKit`-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
frame #10: 0x00000001136f37ac FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
frame #11: 0x00000001136f3b1a FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
frame #12: 0x00000001117aa0a1 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
frame #13: 0x000000011179ffcc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
frame #14: 0x000000011179f483 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 867
frame #15: 0x000000011179ee98 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
frame #16: 0x000000010fa0998d UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 402
frame #17: 0x000000010fa0e676 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 171
* frame #18: 0x000000010ebe8ba1 SWPi2`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff510b7788) + 129 at main.m:7
frame #19: 0x000000011329392d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
frame #20: 0x000000011329392d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Example#2

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x3309b, 0x000000010a95f80b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
frame #0: 0x000000010a95f80b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11
frame #1: 0x00000001090e06f7 UIKit`+[UIWindow _enumerateWindowsIncludingInternalWindows:onlyVisibleWindows:allowMutation:withBlock:] + 143
frame #2: 0x00000001090e049c UIKit`+[UIWindow allWindowsIncludingInternalWindows:onlyVisibleWindows:forScreen:] + 185
frame #3: 0x00000001091f2726 UIKit`-[UIViewController _window] + 315
frame #4: 0x00000001090f6526 UIKit`-[UIView _currentUserInterfaceIdiom] + 85
frame #5: 0x00000001091a4c52 UIKit`-[UITableView setContentOffset:] + 398
frame #6: 0x000000010913910e UIKit`-[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary] + 53
frame #7: 0x00000001091358fa UIKit`-[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollingNotify:pin:tramplingDragFlags:] + 410
frame #8: 0x00000001091217ec UIKit`-[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 113
frame #9: 0x000000010910cb32 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 862
frame #10: 0x0000000109102106 UIKit`__45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 155
frame #11: 0x0000000109102005 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 544
frame #12: 0x000000010910002d UIKit`__UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 213
frame #13: 0x00000001090ffbc9 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 422
frame #14: 0x00000001090cbdeb UIKit`-[UIWindow setRootViewController:] + 774
* frame #15: 0x000000010823904b SWPi2`-[SwpAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](self=0x00007fb6b860bb20, _cmd="application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:", application=0x00007fb6b84021e0, launchOptions=0x0000000000000000) + 155 at SwpAppDelegate.m:29
frame #16: 0x00000001090594ca UIKit`-[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 272
frame #17: 0x000000010905a670 UIKit`-[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3415
frame #18: 0x0000000109060e15 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1755
frame #19: 0x000000010905dff0 UIKit`-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
frame #20: 0x000000010cd477ac FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
frame #21: 0x000000010cd47b1a FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
frame #22: 0x000000010adfe0a1 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
frame #23: 0x000000010adf3fcc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
frame #24: 0x000000010adf3483 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 867
frame #25: 0x000000010adf2e98 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
frame #26: 0x000000010905d98d UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 402
frame #27: 0x0000000109062676 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 171
frame #28: 0x000000010823cba1 SWPi2`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff57a63788) + 129 at main.m:7
frame #29: 0x000000010c8e792d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
frame #30: 0x000000010c8e792d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

What may be specific for iPad Air 2?

Comment: What is in your root view controller? Any KVO? Any conditional code?

Comment: Conditional: no, KVO: applicationWillTerminate and applicationWillResignActive, but after locked this situation is the same.

Comment: Show the KVO code, where its added, removed and what the object is (and when both it and the observer is created and destroyed). What do you mean about locked?

Comment: Simply I was delete it. Any KVO over whole app. And I was delete any timers.

Comment: I'll guess that it's something in your xib or storyboard that's wrong, given that both traces are about nib loading.  What messages do you see in the debug console at the time of the crash?

Comment: Error is in sequence of screen drawing:  NSString *nm = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes........]; and at the end of procedure [nm DEALLOC] instead [nm RELEASE]. Through this many errors appears in many miscellanous places of the code.